# How to compute the loss for a sequence labeling task without the Softmax distribution?

Tags: pytorch, sequence-modeling, loss

For a sequence labeling task (NER), we compute the loss by passing the softmax distribution of the classes (e.g. vocabulary) with the gold label to the loss function (`nn.CrossEntropyLoss(y, x)`):

```
y = tensor([[ 1.4775,  0.7022,  0.7499, -0.7535, -1.4983, -2.3193, -0.6166, -2.3302,
     -0.8847, -0.1915]])
```

label:

```
x = torch.tensor([2])
```

what if we don't have the softmax distribution and we have the predicted label instead, how can we compute the loss? Following the example above, 2 is given for prediction instead of `y`.

Comment: I guess you will need to assume that the predicted class has a probability $1$ and all other classes have probability $0$, unless you have more info. Can you clarify why the predicted classes/labels in your case are hard rather than soft (probabilities)?

Comment: Thanks @nbro .. this is what I actually have done, but I felt that this will confuse the model during training when the predicted label is not the correct one because all the other classes will be treated equally (zeros).